# How to properly render a 404 page in React with React-Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm building a website with React and using React-Router, I'd like to render a 404 page when a url is visited by the user that doesn't exist.

Some urls are dynamic, say,

```
www.site.com/user/(username)
```

How do I render a 404 page with react-router if the user with a particular username doesnt exist? Do I have to manually write code in the component itself during the API calls to check if user exists and then redirect the user to the 404 component?

I'm looking for the best way to redirect the user to a not found page. Looking for ideas on how to do it best.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way is to have the condition in the component matching `user/(username)`. And then either let the component render an error or you can use `<Redirect ... />` to redirect to a error page as described by @canaan seaton

Answer (score 2):

Use Switch then Redirect

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Valid URL no redirect: `/user/valid_username`

404 URL redirects: `/user/invalid_username`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/user/:username" component={Child} />
            <Route path="/404" component={NoMatch} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

function Child({ match }) {
  // perform some username check
  if (match.params.username !== 'valid_username') {
    return (
      <div>
        <Redirect to="/404" />
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>ID: {match.params.username}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

function NoMatch({ location }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        404 - No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code>
      </h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: This doesnt actually tell the browser 'httpcode 404' it tells the browser '200 ok'. when updating the website with new files (for example chunk.js files) and a user going to the website for the firsttime they will get the nomatch page as .js content.

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if `this.props.match.username` exists.  If it does then render as normal if it doesnt then use [React-Router Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) Component to redirect to a `404` component. If you have multiple paths that require this functionality then you may consider making a [HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by rendering a Route with a path of `*`, and React Router will make sure to only render the element if none of the other Routes match.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

For more: https://ui.dev/react-router-handling-404-pages