# React how can i redirect the homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

My problem is ı have a routes like that but when i try for example http://localhost:3000/examp1
I just want to redirect to HomePage how can i do that when i write something http://localhost:3000/*** ı go the page but nothing shows how can i detect and how can i redirect the homepage ? anyone help ?

```
      <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
            <Route path='/xyz' component={asf} exact />
            <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
            <Route path='/fasd/:slug' component={asd} exact />
            <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
            <Route path='/asd/:slug' component={asd} exact />
            <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
            <Route path='/asd' component={fas} exact />
            <Route path='/asd' component={fasd} exact />


          </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `<Route />` at the bottom without a `path` attribute inside the `<Switch>` tag should work for when there's no match, and then use a `<Redirect />` tag to redirect to the homepage.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
        <Route path='/xyz' component={asf} exact />
        <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
        <Route path='/fasd/:slug' component={asd} exact />
        <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
        <Route path='/asd/:slug' component={asd} exact />
        <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
        <Route path='/asd' component={fas} exact />
        <Route path='/asd' component={fasd} exact />

        <Route component={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

[How to properly render a 404 page in React with React-Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694391/how-to-properly-render-a-404-page-in-react-with-react-router)

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Redirect component of react-router-dom library.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
        <Route path='/xyz' component={asf} exact />
        <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
        <Route path='/fasd/:slug' component={asd} />
        <Route path='/asd' component={asd} exact />
        <Route path='/asd/:slug' component={asd} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

DefaultRoute and NotFoundRoute were removed in react-router 1.0.0.

I'd like to emphasize that the default route with the asterisk has to be last in the current hierarchy level to work. Otherwise it will override all other routes that appear after it in the tree because it's first and matches every path.

For react-router 1, 2 and 3

If you want to display a 404 and keep the path (Same functionality as NotFoundRoute)

```html
<Route path='*' exact={true} component={My404Component} />
```

If you want to display a 404 page but change the url (Same functionality as DefaultRoute)

```html
<Route path='/404' component={My404Component} />
<Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
```

Example with multiple levels:

```js
<Route path='/' component={Layout} />
    <IndexRoute component={MyComponent} />
    <Route path='/users' component={MyComponent}>
        <Route path='user/:id' component={MyComponent} />
        <Route path='*' component={UsersNotFound} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/settings' component={MyComponent} />
    <Route path='*' exact={true} component={GenericNotFound} />
</Route>
```

For react-router 4 and 5

Keep the path

```html
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/users" component={MyComponent} />
    <Route component={GenericNotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Redirect to another route (change url)

```html
<Switch>
    <Route path="/users" component={MyComponent} />
    <Route path="/404" component={GenericNotFound} />
    <Redirect to="/404" />
</Switch>
```

The order matters!

Answer (score 0):

I ma using `Navigate` to redirect from "/" to "/home"

```js
import {BrowserRouter, Navigate, Route, Routes,} from "react-router-dom";


  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home"/>} />
      </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```